# scalaz.io : flatten IO[Throwable, Seq[IO[Nothing, String]]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have `IO[Throwable, Seq[IO[Nothing, String]]]` and I would like to turn it into 
`IO[Throwable, Seq[String]]` . Any idea how ? I tried with `flatten` but I get weird implicit missing errors.

```
No implicits found for parameter asTraversable: IO[Nothing, Step] => GenTraversableOnce[B_]
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
val data1: IO[Throwable, Seq[IO[Nothing, String]]]
val data2: IO[Throwable, IO[Nothing, Seq[String]]] = data1.map(IO.sequence)
val data3: IO[Throwable, Seq[String]] = data2.flatten
```

To do it in one step:

```
data1.flatMap(IO.sequence)
```

Courtesy of [@andrey-tyukin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707792/andrey-tyukin)

Comment: How about `data1.flatMap(IO.sequence)`? (not sure whether it compiles, didn't check whether it works out with all the variances)

Comment: oh yeah that's what I did in my code, I was detailing step by step.